# Not able to link file input tag to angular component function

Tags: angular

I am trying to do something very basic in angular . The idea is to just read a log file and display the same in tabular format after processing it and filtering it.

I have completed the heroes tutorial. My project has just one component.

app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>

<app-maindisplay></app-maindisplay>
```

maindisplay.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-maindisplay',
  templateUrl: './maindisplay.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./maindisplay.component.css']
})
export class MaindisplayComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  handleFile(InputFileList: FileList): void {
    console.log('The Handle file got called');
  }
}
```

maindisplay.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:left">
  <input type="file" id="LogFileInput" onchange="handleFile(this.files)">
</div>
```

[image: File dialogue comes up correctly]
The file dialogue box comes up correctly.

However, when the file is selected on chrome console, following error message comes up.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: handleFile is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onchange (localhost/:13)

Can you please help me fix this issue ?
Once the function is called I would be able to handle the file manipulation.

Best Regards,
Vinayak

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `(change)` and pass the `$event` to the method

```
<input type="file" id="LogFileInput" (change)="handleFile($event)">
```

You can access the file in your method using

```
event.target.files
```

Typescript method should look like

```
handleFile(event): void {
   this.files = event.target.files;
   console.log('The Handle file got called');
   console.log(this.files); // logs selected files
}
```